# Windbg not working

Tags: raspberry-pi, windbg, windows-iot-core-10

I'm trying to Kernel Debug Raspberry PI3 using Bus Pirate, I've followed the instructions to connect them, and also the steps from 
 (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/docs/Windbg.htm)
However everytime I run the following command

```
windbg.exe -k com:port=com3,baud=921600
```

but once I restart I get "waiting to reconnect..." and nothing happens? 
Any advice, have you come across this problem? My target is a PI3 and using the latest, 10.0.14393.693 version of Win 10 IoT Core.

Comment: not sure why this is downvoted? do I need to improve the question? instead of just downvoting try to add some reasons along with it...

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by  running the following on Raspberry PI

```
bcdedit /dbgsettings serial debugport:1 baudrate:115200
```

On the Host machine running the baudrate of the following

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x86>windbg.exe -k com:port=COM3,baud=921600
```